# pygame sets position of all instances of class to the same value for some reason?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm making a snake game in pygame and i've run into a problem. Whenever the snake eats food, the player gains a point. From that point on a tail is created behind the snake whenever it moves. Only the tails the number of player points away from the snake head will be drawn while the rest are deleted. The problem arises when i'm creating the tails. Whenever i create an instance of the tail, i have to get the position of the snake head and subtract away a value equal to the snake size in the opposite direction. That's where the tail will be drawn. However the position of all the tails are set to the same value for some reason and i cant't figure out why that is. I'm using my own library so i cant post it in here but iv'e determined it's not the cause.

```
    import pygame as pg

    from random import randrange

    import widget


    # disp -> display properties
    disp = widget.get_json("config", ["display"])

    food = widget.Surface(image="../images/food.png", pos=[0, 0])

    def set_food_pos(snake):
        while True:
            pos = [randrange(0, disp["size"][_], disp["cell"]) for _ in range(2)]
            safe = 0

            for tail in snake.tails:
                if tail.pos != pos: safe += 1

            if safe == len(snake.tails):
                food.pos = pos
                food.rect.topleft = food.pos

                break


    class Snake(widget.Sprite):
        """ Snake: main playable sprite """

        SIZE = [disp["cell"]] * 2
        KEYS = [[276, 275], [273, 274]]

        def __init__(self):
            self.image = pg.image.load("../images/snake_head.png")
            self.pos = widget.VEC(0, 0)

            super().__init__(pg.sprite.GroupSingle)

            self.axis, self.orient, self.do_move = 0, 1, False
            self.past, self.delay = pg.time.get_ticks(), 150
            self.speed, self.vel = disp["cell"], [-1, 1]
            self.alive, self.points = True, 0
            self.tails = [self]

        def control(self, key):
            axis = [0 if key in Snake.KEYS[0] else 1][0]
            if axis != self.axis:
                if self.do_move:
                    self.axis = axis
                    self.orient = Snake.KEYS[axis].index(key)
                    self.do_move = False

        def time_base_movement(self):
            now = pg.time.get_ticks()
            if now - self.past >= self.delay:
                self.do_move = True
                self.pos[self.axis] += self.vel[self.orient] * self.speed
                self.past = pg.time.get_ticks()

        def eat_food(self):
            if food.rect.contains(self.rect):
                set_food_pos(self)
                self.points += 1

        def create_tail(self):
            if self.points:
                if self.do_move:
                    pos = [_ for _ in self.rect.topleft]
                    pos[self.axis] += self.vel[::-1][self.orient] * 20
                    tail = widget.Sprite(image="../images/snake_head.png", pos=pos)

                    self.tails.insert(0, tail)

        def render_tails(self, surface):
            if self.points > 0:
                tails = self.tails[:-1]

                for tail in tails[0:self.points]: tail.group.draw(surface)
                [self.tails.remove(tail) for tail in tails[self.points:]]

        def check_boundary_collision(self):
            for _ in range(2):
                if self.pos[_] > disp["size"][_] - Snake.SIZE[_]:self.alive = False
                elif self.pos[_] < 0: self.alive = False

            for tail in self.tails[:-1]:
                if tail.rect.contains(self.rect): self.alive = False

        def reset_properties(self):
            if self.alive == False:
                print([tail.pos for tail in self.tails[:-1]])
                self.tails = [self]
                self.do_move = False

                self.pos = widget.VEC([0, 0])
                self.rect.topleft = self.pos

                self.axis, self.orient = 0, 1
                self.points, self.alive = 0, True

                set_food_pos(self)

        def update(self):
            if self.alive:
                self.time_base_movement()
                self.check_boundary_collision()
                self.reset_properties()

                self.rect.topleft = self.pos
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it seems python doesn't create a new copy of an attribute each time it is assigned to a different attribue. Instead the new attribute points to the assigned attribute. The fix for this is the "deepcopy" method in the built in module "copy".

Exe: new_value = copy.deepcopy(old_value)